# How to make lactose free mashed potatoes

Tags: potatoes, soy, dairy-free

To begin with, I use soy cream instead of dairy-based cream.  It tastes alright, but not superb, and it seems to require more salt. What is missing that I should find a substitute to add back in?

Comment: It sounds like you might have a recipe (or at least ingredient list and desired result) in mind using dairy - if you could edit your question and add that, it'd be easier for people to help make a lactose-free version. There's a ton of variety in mashed potatoes.

Answer (score 3):

By "cream" do you mean "milk?" If you are lactose intolerant, I suggest some margarine and either sour cream or yogurt.  If you have a lactose allergy, still margarine, more alternate dairy products, and some kind of spice mix, like an Italian seasoning.

Comment: I mean heavy milk cream. I would gladly use sour cream but that bothers me too.

Answer (score 3):

I made some this past week with a little olive oil (maybe 1 tablespoon?) and a little almond milk (maybe 1 teaspoon?). (I am unable to eat dairy.) I also had a rutebega mashed in--one rutebega to 4 Russet potatoes. It was delicious and even my husband, who can eat all the dairy he wants, thought they were just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the rutebega addition.  That sounds yummy. I am surprised you use so little liquid though, I usually add 1/2 pint to 4 large Russet potatoes.

Answer (score 1):

Mashed potatoes do not require anything to be added?

Use a fresh potato variety suitable for mashing (check with you local vegetable supplier), all you need is to mash them, and introduce some air by using a whipping process (a fork will do)

People typically add milk or cream to old or dry potatoes. Use a better potato for better results without adding anything. Reserve some of the boiling liquid to fluff up dry potatoes a little if required

Comment: This is very much a matter of taste. Even with wonderful potatoes, some people will prefer some creaminess or fat.

Answer (score 1):

I've been told that ghee has no lactose in it, so that might be one alternative to butter, but not to the milk, as I find you need some water-based liquid to get the consistency I like -- you're rupturing starch into the liquid, which gives a creamy mouthfeel.

I personally [use stock, not milk](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/7197/67) to adjust the liquid in my potatoes.  You have to adjust the salt, but I personally prefer it.  (and it has nothing with my not being able to eat dairy.)  You can add some olive oil to change the mouth feel, although too much and it's pretty obvious it's olive oil in there.

As milk is sweet, you might also consider adding a bit of other root vegetables like carrots or sweet potatoes in, but that'll significantly change the color, which the kids may not like (or they may love ... you never know).  If you use carrots, you'll want to start them cooking while you're prepping the pototes, so they get a head start on the cooking, and it doesn't hurt to cut them a bit thinner.

Answer (score 1):

You can add fried bacon, and be sure to include the fat rendered off while frying to compensate for the lack of butter.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have butter (some people can, as the amount of lactose remaining is small), that can add a rich fattiness that soymilk sometimes lacks. Another good add-in is roasted garlic cloves, which you can mash with the potatoes -- I find even with dairy in them, that kicks the potatoes up to the next level quite handily. I usually find milk and soymilk interchangeable, but almost always add butter and/or garlic.

Comment: Yup, I can have some butter so I do add that, and I agree that garlic works wonders.  Though at the end of the day I am trying to make my lactose free mashed potatoes taste really close to dairy ones which my kids adore.

Interesting enough I replaced milk to make oatmeal with soy milk and get far superior results than using milk and of course water.  Then again it's all about the pallate.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried lactose free milk and I was surprised how good it was.  I love milk. My mother not so much.  She can't have dairy at all.

I go to the Asian markets, sometimes health food stores.  They have a dairy free cream cheese that was surprisingly good. I use that when my mother visits.  Add seasoning last so not to over-season.  To thin and smooth it out, us a little of the potato water or a little soy milk.  If you don't, it will be very lumpy. I didn't find just using soy milk as good.

You should check out their other non diary items.  Not to shabby, some brands better then the other.  Also, Smart Balance makes a margarine that is non dairy.  Pretty good.

Comment: I could imagine adding most of the products you list to mashed potatoes. But waffles ?!

Comment: Sorry, I was just pointing out that there are also non dairy waffles that are pretty good.  My goof!